# Using the Redirect to XPages Login Snippet without the OpenNTF Domino API

Tags: xpages

I am attempting to implement the Redirect to XPages Login Snippet by Paul Withers in my XPages application.

https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=redirect-to-xpages-login-page

His code is making use of the OpenNTF Domino API which I unfortunately cannot use on production servers due to company polices. Therefore I am trying to replace line 89 using lotus.domino API.

Line 89:

`if (!Factory.getSession().getEffectiveUserName().equalsIgnoreCase("anonymous")) {`

Creating a session using lotus.domino API requires credentials so how would I go about checking if the user is anonymous without using the OpenNTF Domino API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at JSFUtil used in several XPages project. With JSFUtil you can easily find the effective user name like this:

```
JSFUtil.getSession().getEffectiveUserName();
```

The following helper methods from JSFUtil are used for this:

```
public static Session getSession() {
    return (Session) resolveVariable("session");
}

public static Object resolveVariable(String variable) {
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), variable);
}
```

**Update:** As Paul Withers points out, you can use ExtLibUtil from the XPages Extension Library for this too (with no need to use JSFUtil):

```
ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession().getEffectiveUserName();
```

Comment: A good starter for `JSFUtil` is Tim Tripcony's version of it. There are plenty of others out there with additions, but this is a great start, especially if you're looking to define your own customizations. https://github.com/timtripcony/com.timtripcony.domino.collections/blob/master/com.timtripcony.domino.collections/Code/Java/com/timtripcony/util/JSFUtil.java

Comment: Thanks @EricMcCormick for the link

Comment: As far as I know, all the JSFUtil methods are now available in ExtLibUtil, and I would recommend using that.